# php strtotime problems, giving incorrect values?

Tags: php, strtotime

I have this code:

```
$date = '2010-03-08 8:10:20'
$new_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . " +1 month"));
echo $new_date;
```

Btw, I already set

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

And the result is: 5 April 2010, 3 days missing. Why is it happen? I heard they are some bugs in strtotime? If thats the case, how to get a correct one? I mean, is there another way to replace this:

```
$new_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . " +1 month")); // or +2, +3... +100
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$date = '2010-03-08 8:10:20';
$new_date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . " +1 month"));
echo $new_date;
```

and get

```
2010-04-08 08:10:20
```

so you've got some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use mktime Function :

```
$date = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime ( arguments ) + one_month_epoch_value) ) ;
```

Comment: Don't use this.  I know this is old, but it's fairly badly broken.  It uses apparent variables without $ signs, adds a fixed month value to the result of mktime() when +1 month, could be 28,29,30 or 31 days, depending on what the next month is.  I think the intention was to add +1 to the value of the month as passed to mktime().